# CSS font-size in IE not working properly?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-size

I am using twitter bootstrap and have a input field which i want to have bigger sized fonts 
so i use

```
    input#lookup{
    font-size: 72px;
    height: 90px;
    width: 400px; 
}
```

and the bootstrap classes i use on the input field

```
<input type="text" name="lookup" value="" id="lookup" class="input-large search-query">
```

But when i put some text in it get cut-off
[image: Why does this happen in IE?]

btw: where is a chrome developbar like for IE

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a working solution i hope by adding

```
line-height: 1.1em;
```